# GIT: Can only push to remote from specific pwd?

Tags: git, github, repository

Working on a repo with a remote, and everything works as expected if I am in the outmost folder.  If I go one folder deeper within the structure, I can no longer see the git log or push to the repo.  What is going on - I thought that so long as the `pwd` is within the repo I could commit files and push?

While not a huge problem (as I can easily navigate to the correct folder and commit from there), it is a bit of a pain.

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure that you have submodules. What does this command show? `git submodule status --recursive`

Comment: That command shows nothing